# Any link to the suspicious for Google website

Tags: firefox, warnings

He, can you share any link to the suspicious by google (stopbadware) website? I need any example of link, which will result like [that](http://www.google.com/help/hc/images/search_45449b_en.gif) or [that](http://www.blogjer.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/aw_firefox.png). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check sites for being suspicious:
http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=nmei.co.cc/

For example, *nmei.co.cc* is listed as suspicious and shows exactly the same error.